# html2pdf how to prevent table row from breaking midway

Tags: html, css, pdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

I am trying to use html2pdf to download the HTML page as PDF however if the content of the table is too long, it tends to break the TR midway through.

Any solutions for this issue?

[image]

## Attempted Solutions (None worked)

### Solution #1: `pagebreak: { avoid: ['tr', 'td'] }`

```
var opt = {
        margin: 0.5,
        filename: dashboard_name + '_' + client_name + '.pdf',
        pagebreak: { avoid: ['tr', 'td'] },
        image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
        html2canvas: { dpi: 192, width: $(window).width()},
        jsPDF: {
            orientation: pageOrient,
            unit: 'cm',
            format: 'a2',
            compress: true
        }
    };
```

### Solution #2: Adding page break CSS

```
@media print {
            table, div   {
                break-inside: avoid;
            }
        }
    
        thead { display: table-header-group; }
        tfoot { display: table-row-group;}
        tr {
        page-break-after: always!important;
        page-break-before: always!important;
        page-break-inside: auto!important;

    }
```

### Solution #3: `      pagebreak: {

```
    mode: ['avoid-all', 'css', 'legacy']
},`
```

However, the table row is still breaking across 2 pages as depicted in the image below.
[image]

Comment: Dear @YeoBryan, Could you please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that one can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @YeoBryan, do you find solution?

Answer (score 4):

## Introduction

Let's consider the following versions as the current versions:

- `html2pdf.js`: `0.10.1`.

## Solution

The default page-break modes: `['css', 'legacy']`.

Adding the `avoid-all` page-break mode resolves the problem:

```
const opt = {
    <…>,
    pagebreak: {
        mode: ['avoid-all', 'css', 'legacy']
    },
    <…>
};
```

Please, refer to the documentation section: [html2pdf.js | Client-side HTML-to-PDF rendering using pure JS. | Options | Page-breaks](https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/#page-breaks).

### Test evidence

#### Draft example HTML page (`index.html`) after applying solution

Please, note and address the TODO-note appropriately.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>HTML table</title>
        <style>
            table {
                font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
            }

            td, th {
                border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 8px;
            }

            tr:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: #dddddd;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"
                integrity="sha512-GsLlZN/3F2ErC5ifS5QtgpiJtWd43JWSuIgh7mbzZ8zBps+dvLusV+eNQATqgA/HdeKFVgA5v3S/cIrLF7QnIg=="
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HTML table</h1>

        <button onclick="printTable()">
            Print to PDF
        </button>

        <table id="long-table">
            <tr>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
            <!-- TODO: Duplicate the below row many times. -->
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <script defer>
            function printTable() {
                const element = document.getElementById('long-table');
                var opt = {
                    pagebreak: {
                        mode: ['avoid-all', 'css', 'legacy']
                    }
                };
                html2pdf(element, opt);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Before applying solution

[image: Before applying solution]

#### After applying solution

[image: After applying solution]

## Additional references

An additional example:

- GitHub issue: [text is cut in the middle · Issue #83 · eKoopmans/html2pdf.js](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/issues/83).
- GitHub comment: **[dgolhar](https://github.com/dgolhar)** commented [on Nov 29, 2019](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/issues/83#issuecomment-559780370).

Comment: Thanks, will follow up on this tomorrow when I am back at work to see if it works! @SergeyVyacheslavovichBrunov

Comment: The solution didnt work, the row is still breaking across 2 pages. I have updated the original post with the results of attempting this solution

Comment: Dear @YeoBryan, Thank you for the update! Requested the reproducible example (please, see the comments to the question).

Comment: Hello, @YeoBryan! I have updated the answer with a minimal and complete example. Could you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

here problem is that the `@0.9.0` version of `html2pdf` doesn't support the content break option so please update your `html2pdf` version to `@0.10.1` or the latest.